# Importing Advanced Digitizing Panel (CADInput) to plugin (custom toolbar)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, digitizing, toolbar

[image]

How to add a CADInput (Advanced Digitizing Panel) to the plugin to click when we want to show us an Advanced Digitizing Panel(because I'm trying to make my toolbar), is there any chance to do this?

Comment: I solved this,                                                                      self.Action=[self.iface.viewMenu().actions()[25].menu().actions()[7]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
if self._iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().isVisible():
    self._iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().hide()
else:
    self._iface.advancedDigitizeToolBar().show()
```